Openshift use Custom Maven setting file for springboot project
I'm trying to import springboot project from git. And try to update the buildConfig to have custom maven setting point to Nexus repo with credentials.
tried to config MAVEN_MIRROR_URL in buildConfig, it successfully point to nexus repo. But not sure how to handle credential part.
tried to create configMap that has maven setting. and included in buildConfig. didnt work.
Can someone please help?
